# react-native-navigation BottomTab Style

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

## Issue Description

How can we style the bottom tabs container in `react-native-navigation`? For example if we want to increase the vertical padding and change the top border color?

## Environment

- React Native Navigation version: 6.12.2
- React Native version: 0.63.2
- Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): both
- Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): Any

Answer (score 1):

For changing border color you can use the code below. i didn't find anything related to vertical padding in documentation

```
bottomTabs: {
   borderColor: 'red',
   borderWidth: 0.1,
}
```

Check this [comment for more details](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/pull/6915#issue-789357570)

Comment: But how to remove the border completely, a question from a5med